# How can I let HTML input tags remembers data in them even though refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

My coworker is getting stressed out from loading data when she refresh or leave the page she was working on by mistake. So, I wanna let HTML input tags remember what she types in that case.

I was searching about how to do it, and I found a few ways such as `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Since I'm new to web development areas, I wanna make sure if they are actual ways for web developers to implement the feature.

Can I go with `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` in that case?
or can anyone suggest an idea to do that?

Comment: Yes, `localStorage` will hold the values between page visits. Just Google `localStorage` and you'll find lots of documentation on how to implement it. Stack Overflow isn't the right place to look for general tutorials.

Comment: Yes, I already found many documentations for it, but I wasn't sure if it's the actual way that many web developers use. So, I needed to make sure if I'm going for the right direction :) Thank you!

Comment: You could also use something like this to serialize / deserialize your form data -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-form-serializer

Comment: You can also use a utility like https://github.com/geuis/argon to help when storing and retrieving data from local and session storage.